Did my professor mis-state the definition of the orientable double cover of a non-orientable manifold $M$?
The definition given to us is exactly as follows:
Extra Credit: Let $M^n$ be a non-orientable differentiable manifold. For each $p \in M$ consider the set $B$ of bases of $T_pM$ and say that two bases are equivalent if they are related by a matrix with positive determinant. This is an equivalence relation and separates $B$ into two disjoint sets. Let $\mathfrak{D}_p$ be the quotient space of $B$ with respect to this equivalence relation. Then $O_p \in \mathfrak{D}_p$ will be called an orientation of $T_pM$. Let $\overline M$ be the set $ \overline M = \{ (p,O_p); p \in M, O_p \in \mathfrak{D}_p \}$...
My professor goes on to give a differentiable structure for $\overline M$.
My confusion is with the definition of $\mathfrak{D}_p$. $B$ is just a set, correct? It is not a topological space and hence we don't have a quotient space by the equivalence relation given. I am just grappling with this material for the first time, so I am not confident in my ability to determine what the correct quotient space in question is.
I have tried looking this up, but everything I have found seems to assume I already understand what $\mathfrak{D}_p$ is, and I do not.
Any help is appreciated.

Suppose $n\geq 1$. As you have written it, yes, $B$ is just a set (the set of ordered bases for the vector space $T_pM$). We have a certain equivalence relation $\sim$ defined on the set $B$. This has exactly two equivalence classes, and $\mathfrak{D}_p:=B/\sim$ is precisely this two element set, consisting of the two equivalence classes of $\sim$ in $B$.
Just to be clear: having two equivalence classes means we have two subsets $\mathcal{O}_1,\mathcal{O}_2\subset B$ such that $\mathcal{O}_1\cup\mathcal{O}_2=B$, $\mathcal{O}_1\cap\mathcal{O}_2=\emptyset$, and $\mathcal{O}_1,\mathcal{O}_2$ are non-empty. Then, $\mathfrak{D}_p=\{\mathcal{O}_1,\mathcal{O}_2\}$ is this two-element set.

Your remark

It is not a topological space and hence we don't have a quotient space by the equivalence relation given.

strikes me as a little odd. When you say “quotient space”, I guess you mean ‘equipped with a certain topology’? Anyway, note that if you have any set $X$, and any equivalence relation $R$ on $X$, you can always consider the quotient set $X/R$, and this comes of course with a surjective map $\pi:X\to X/R$. If you now start with a topology on $X$, then you can induce a topology on $X/R$, called the quotient topology, which is the largest topology on $X/R$ such that $\pi$ is a continuous map.

Anyway, I should mention, that you could give $B$ a very natural topology, since $B$ is in fact just the set of isomorphisms $\Bbb{R}^n\to T_pM$, meaning it is an open subset of the vector space $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{R}^n,T_pM)$ (btw: this is a finite-dimensional real vector space, so even if there is no canonical norm here, all the norms give rise to the same topology; this is known as the equivalence of norms in finite-dimensions). So, the thing is $B$, for your situation, is to be treated as just a set, but just know that it can be given a very natural topology as well.

Thank you for the clear and full description. I was confused primarily by the term 'quotient space' for the set, since so far, this phrase has been reserved for the quotient of a topological space by an equivalence relation.

@StevenCripe Yea I figured that’s what the issue was. In my mind, the terms “space”, “set”, “collection” are all interchangeable. I don’t like to encode technical hypotheses into the everyday word “space”, so I’d explicitly mention topological space or vector space or measure space or whatever else the case might be. I know some people do require technical hypotheses in the term space, but I just find that silly and counterproductive, because it’s never going to be a standardized term.
